# Change Json response in passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Can you please tell me how to change JSON response to request with wrong api token.

I mean instead

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

I want to do this way

```
{
    "error": true,
    "message": "Unauthenticated.",

}
```

Where should i change this ? Thank you

Comment: You can probably rely on the status code of the response; `2xx` response codes are ok, `4xx` errors are auth/permission/request/response related, `5xx` errors are server issues, etc etc. Your AJAX/api request handler should be able to distinguish between an error and an ok response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project's `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file there is a function called `render()`. Inside that function add the following code block:

```
if($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException){
  return response()->json(['error' => true, 'message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
}
```